# AWS Batch Array Job with Varying containerOverrides

Tags: aws-batch

Is it possible to submit ~200 jobs in a singular batch array job [via boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/batch/client/submit_job.html) with a different [containerOverrides](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/batch/client/submit_job.html#command) per each job in the array?

In this case, I cannot modify the container used in the JobDefinition, therefore using the `$AWS_BATCH_JOB_ARRAY_INDEX` environment variable as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/array_index_example.html) would not work (I don't think ...)

Comment: yes, you cannot modify the job definition but you can override the configuration in job definition with a new configuration while submitting a new job

Comment: I have a similar use case. Did you end up solving this @Oliver?

Comment: @Howard_Roark Yes, use `$AWS_BATCH_JOB_ARRAY_INDEX`  in the container command :) Hope this helps